# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.12.4 or higher, but lower than version 3 in date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I like to add this https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-a-datetime-picker-to-your-forms.stml date time picker in my form. this blog explain clearly how to add date time picker

I'm trying to add this datetime picker in my angularjs form it viewed by datetime picker is not opened getting an error message

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.12.4
>   or higher, but lower than version 3

i don't know what to do for it,please help me with it

Comment: Did you include jquery in your webpage? It should be included before bootstrap and datepicker

Answer (score 1):

Just update Bootstrap to version 3.3.7